# Expanding Jade phoenix mage's maneuvers?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, prestige-class, tome-of-battle, combat-maneuver

I was reading the tome of battle and found this in jade phoenix mage

> Maneuvers: At
>   each odd-numbered level, you gain a new maneuver known from the **Desert Wind or Devoted Spirit disciplines.** You must meet a maneuver’s prerequisite to learn it. You add your full Jade Phoenix mage levels to your initiator level to determine your total initiator level and your highest-level maneuvers known. At 3rd level, 6th level, and 9th level, you gain an additional maneuver readied per day.

Emphasis mine.

I want to build a warblade gish yaddayadda the same guy as before; but I want to keep learning warblade maneuvers (specifically diamond mind maneuvers for Time Stands Still and the various high level nightmare blades). Is there a method of gaining these other maneuvers with the jade mage?

Comment: Besides the martial study feat or taking more levels in warblade, you mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Not really

There is no official way to change or augment the list of disciplines that a given class offers. Can’t prove a negative, but *Tome of Battle* was one of the last books published, and its material is referenced almost nowhere outside itself (*Dragons of Eberron* is the only book I know of that does so). *Tome of Battle*, itself, certainly has nothing of the sort.

### You can always use Martial Study

The Martial Study feat exists for this purpose, to get a few maneuvers that you wouldn’t otherwise get. You could use it to get up to three select Diamond Mind maneuvers, and you will be able to use your warblade initiator level (including jade phoenix mage levels), readied maneuvers (including those from jade phoenix mage), and recovery for them.

### Carefully alternating between warblade and jade phoenix mage can also work

You can always take a carefully-timed warblade level to gain a maneuver from it at a particular initiator level.

### Houseruling this is fairly popular

*Which* disciplines you have access to is far more a matter of thematics than it is balance; Devoted Spirit, Shadow Hand, and White Raven are kind of the “best” disciplines and Desert Wind and Stone Dragon are kind of the “worst” disciplines, but honestly they’re all pretty close. Swapping one discipline for another is very close to power-neutral.